# What type of transistor is this

Tags: transistors, pcb

I can't seem to find what type of transistor this is based on the markings. It's broken, so I need to replace it. It is in a Chrysler Jeep radio from 1995. The letters are "CBRP".  Thanks.
[image]

Comment: How do you know it's broken? What is it supposed to do? What is it doing?

Comment: Is it related to a CB Radio antenna, used within cars?

Comment: @MCG The radio isn't turning on and I've been doing a lot of troubleshooting.  This transistor has a crack between the "R" and "P" so I'm going to try to replace it.

Comment: @Michel Keijzers No, It's just a regular car radio/cassette player.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be a BCX68-10 from Infineon. It also has a SOT-89 package and has the marking "CB". If this is true then it is an NPN BJT, 1A collector current, 20V Vce rated. Datasheet here:

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/bcx68.pdf?folderId=db3a304314dca38901155ffc06d51dc7&fileId=db3a3043156fd573011589ef403903e7

Not certain about this though, as the diagram doesn't quite match up:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll track one down and try it.  I'm going to leave the question unanswered for a bit to see if others have an idea.

Comment: Sure thing. Like I said things don't quite match up, so I'd be hesitant to accept  this answer myself. Keep us posted!